# Lightsail+ STS to obtain temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-lightsail, assume-role

Is it possible to retrieve [temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_temporary.html) from within a Lightsail instance without storing user credentials within ENV or an AWS credentials file? If possible, I'd like to use those temporary credentials to assume a service role with the necessary permissions to my AWS resources.

I was hoping it'd be possible to grant permission to the instance ARN (similar to EC2) but I haven't been able to figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the frustrating situation is, amazon lightsail is managed outside of your aws account, in short, there's no support for instance profile like in ec2

the only way to access aws resources from your lightsail instance is to use an iam user with correct credentials